# Rendering Dynamic Select Options

Tags: vue.js

I have a form that is currently using jQuery to:

1. Do a series of ajax requests
2. Dynamically change select options based on the returned data.

I thought this would be something nice to reimplement in vue.js as a learning experience. But I am running into a snag with what is the best way to add dynamic options to a `<select>`.

This link in the docs (http://012.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Dynamic_Select_Options) looks like exactly what I need but I am having issues replicating it in my code below. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Any tips are appreciated!

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="add-match-template">
    <select v-model="selected_game" options="games"></select>
</script>

<div id="add_match_form">
    <add-match-form></add-match-form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Vue.component('add-match-form', {
        template: '#add-match-template',
        data: function() {
            return {
                games: [
                    {'value': 1, 'text': 'Game 1'},
                    {'value': 4, 'text': 'Game 4'}
                ],
                selected_game: null
            }
        }
    })

    new Vue({
        el: "#add_match_form"
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Try adding `:` before options so it becomes `:options="games"`. I'll post an answer if it works but that looks like the first thing to check.

Comment: Are you using Vue 2? The documentation you link is very old.

Comment: @BertEvans ah how could I not of caught that. I am using version 2.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Vue 2, you no longer bind options that way. Here is the [current documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select).

```
Vue.component('add-match-form', {
  template: '#add-match-template',
  data: function() {
    return {
      games: [
        {'value': 1, 'text': 'Game 1'},
        {'value': 4, 'text': 'Game 4'}
      ],
      selected_game: null
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#add_match_form"
})
```

Template:

```
<div id="add_match_form">
    <add-match-form></add-match-form>
</div>

<template id="add-match-template">
  <select v-model="selected_game">
    <option v-for="game in games" :value="game.value">{{game.text}}</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

**Working Example**

```js
console.clear()


Vue.component('add-match-form', {
  template: '#add-match-template',
  data: function() {
    return {
      games: [
        {'value': 1, 'text': 'Game 1'},
        {'value': 4, 'text': 'Game 4'}
      ],
      selected_game: null
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#add_match_form"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="add_match_form">
    <add-match-form></add-match-form>
</div>

<template id="add-match-template">
  <select v-model="selected_game">
    <option v-for="game in games" :value="game.value">{{game.text}}</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

Comment: I can't believe I did not realize I was in the old docs. I did try something like this too and was having issues because I was trying to do something like this `<option v-for="(value, text) in games" value="value">{{text}}</option>`. So thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: @jsm1th I stumble over the doc issue often, so I check now :)

Comment: @BertEvans can I ask you one more quick question? what would be the best way to listen for a change on that select? so like when an option from that select is picked I want to make an ajax call and populate another select with results of that call

Comment: @jsm1th you could `watch` the selected value, or use a `@change` handler on the select.

Comment: @jsm1th It would be better to use the `change` handler if you only want it triggering for the selection change otherwise the watcher will be firing any time you modify that value (I don't know how your code will be working). Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: `value="game.value"` should be `:value="game.value"`

Comment: @Tharanga Good catch.

Comment: @djxak Thanks! Moved it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
  <select v-on:change="setCenter" v-model="market">
                        <option v-for="(item,index) in markets"
                                v-bind:key="index" :value="index">{{item.name}} 
                        </option>
  </select>
```

Dont forget about v-bind:key, also map value using :value otherwise default value would not be selected. I use index here as value but you can use item property. Index is better as it is easy to find object in array when index changes.